# Compiling my project with AOT throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to build an uberjar using `lein uberjar`. During compiling, the following gets thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(/tmp/form-init8223412427040046857.clj:1:73)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.string$lower_case.invokeStatic(string.clj:217)
    at clojure.string$lower_case.invoke(string.clj:213)
    at kappa.joke_classifier$is_jokable_QMARK_.invokeStatic(joke_classifier.clj:32)
    at kappa.joke_classifier$is_jokable_QMARK_.invoke(joke_classifier.clj:29)
    at kappa.core$maybe_joke.invokeStatic(core.clj:47)
    at kappa.core$maybe_joke.invoke(core.clj:45)
    at clojure.core$run_BANG_$fn__7276.invoke(core.clj:7393)
    at clojure.lang.PersistentVector.reduce(PersistentVector.java:341)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6544)
    at clojure.core$run_BANG_.invokeStatic(core.clj:7388)
    at clojure.core$run_BANG_.invoke(core.clj:7388)
    at kappa.core$run.invokeStatic(core.clj:58)
    at kappa.core$run.invoke(core.clj:53)
    at kappa.core$_main.invokeStatic(core.clj:66)
    at kappa.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:61)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
    at user$eval5.invokeStatic(form-init8223412427040046857.clj:1)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init8223412427040046857.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    ... 14 more
```

The code using string/lower-case looks as follows:

```
(defn is-jokable? [msg]
  (and
    (> 30 (count msg))
    (= :positive (.classify classifier (str/lower-case msg)))
    (< 1 (:positive (.probabilities classifier (str/lower-case msg))))))
```

As can be seen from the stack trace, my `-main` function calls a function that eventually calls `is-jokable`, and `str/lower-case` seems to be called with `nil`. If I understand correctly this is because of the AOT compilation happening for uberjars, but I'm not quite sure why exactly this problem occurs... I've already tried to read up on AOT, but didn't find anything helpful. Can you explain the inner workings of AOT to me?

Comment: Could you give all the relevant code as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Is AOT required to run your code?  Does it run without the AOT compilation?  You didn't say.  AOT just means that certain files are compiled first, before anything much runs, as opposed to being compiled on an as-needed basis.  (That's the general idea.  I'm sure there are subtleties that my statement doesn't capture.)

Comment: Aren't there some trivial things you could do to track down the error?  Why blame AOT?  Where is `msg` coming from?  Have you tried a debugger or something simpler like adding print statements or tests for `nil`?  `count` will return 0 for `nil`. The `nil` must be coming from somewhere; look there.    Maybe these comments are too obvious.  My apologies if I just don't understand, but you haven't told us anything about the context.  If this error is only happening with AOT compilation, I wonder whether you can avoid it by AOT compiling the files in a different order.  Just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost embarrassed I have posted this, it must have been too late in the night... ;)

I got completely distracted by the `compiling` and `invokeStatic` hints in the stacktrace, and just now found that this was indeed an everyday bug where I expected a map to contain a key/value pair that wasn't existent, leading to `nil` being passed to the function in question.

Thanks for the helpful comments!